# Bootstrap datepicker with button only

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to use the bootstrap-datepicker plugin to allow the user to click a button and then choose a date on the calendar. I am having trouble getting the calendar to appear on button click:

```
<button class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></button>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").datepicker();
})

$("button").click(function(){
  $("button").datepicker('show');
})
```

Here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/cavanflynn/pen/RWxmdK

Unless I am misreading the documentation, this should make it appear. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try to load stable jQuery version (not 3 alpha) and include it before datepicker.

Comment: I am using a stable version on my site. That was just the first one on codepen

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmVLWv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including the items in the wrong order, include jQuery first and then the library as it depends on jQuery (*also as mentioned used a stable version of jQuery*).

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avEgOz

```
[first]  https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js
[second] https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js
```